# pip --version failed on msys2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

installed:

1. mingw-w64-x86_64-python-pip 21.0.1-2
2. mingw-w64-x86_64-python 3.8.8-2

environment variable:

1. PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/mingw64/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bin\msys64\mingw64\bin\pip-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')())
  File "C:\bin\msys64\mingw64\bin\pip-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import plistlib
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "C:/bin/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pyexpat: ▒Ҳ▒▒▒ָ▒▒▒▒ģ▒顣
[0x7FF8AD8DE0A4] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
[0x7FF8AD8DE0A4] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
```

please help me, big brother

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip? (python -m pip uninstall pip, then https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: I reinstall pip again, it does not work (pacman reinstall).  python -m pip uninstall pip still fails. I remove all msys2 files, and install python and pip, it works.  i think it's msys2's version reason.  you  niubility, bro